# Can't call method of form object passed to child

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm trying to apply this tutorial, though what I'm doing is not exactly the same: [tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/20)

I've successfully passed the form object to my child component. I can reference the properties of the form object without problems. `console.log(this.form)` also returns shows the methods inside the form object, but calling `this.form.$method()` fails.

This is in my root:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        form: new Form({
            //form data
        }),
    },
});
```

This is in my component, which throws an `Uncaught TypeError: this.form.$post is not a function` when calling store:

```
export default {
    props: [
        'form',
    ],
    methods: {
        store() {
            this.form.$post(url);
        },
    },
}
```

This is in my form helper class:

```
class Form {
    post(url) {
        return this.$http.post(url, {
            //form data
        }).then((response) => {
            //success
        }, (error) => {
            //error
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, `url` isn't being passed and isn't defined in your `store()` method.

Comment: Nah, that's just a simplification. I typed in the url manually in the actual method. Anyway, I just gave up and imported the class directly. I think vue is more concerned with passing data then with passing methods in objects.

Answer (score 0):

You've named your method `post` and you're trying to call it with `$post`.

Try changing:

```
this.form.$post(url);
```

to:

```
this.form.post(url);
```

Hope this helps!